# Parsing SharePoint's WebPart UserProperties - value States

Tags: web-part, database

I'm working on a parser that is able to parse data directly from SharePoint .mdf database.

Currently I'm working on parsing data in binary column `tp_AllUsersProperties`. I'm able to parse pretty much everything, but I can't figure out what is inside `States` value. It seems to be some key-value collection (dictionary).

Below are the contents of a single row inside `tp_AllUserProperties`:

| Name | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "Description" | System.String | "$Resources:Microsoft.Office.Server.Search,SearchBoxScriptWP_Desc;" |
| "ImportErrorMessage" | System.String | "$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;" |
| **"States"** | System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object> | { } |

Do you know what should I modify inside the webpart to put some data into this `States` collection?

Comment: I'm not an admin, but I think directly modifying the SharePoint system or content databases is a violation of the license agreement and could make you ineligible for support. I realize some of the on-premises versions of SharePoint are out of support anyway, so maybe it's a non-factor for you. Just thought it was worth a mention.

Comment: Hi Rob,
We do not modify these values, we just parse & read them. But thanks for the insight, I was not aware of that.

Comment: For reference here’s Microsoft’s article on accessing/modifying SharePoint databases:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/support-for-changes-to-the-databases-that-are-used-by-office-server-products-and-by-windows-sharepoint-services-502c6da1-be7e-39b0-0ea8-8b4ebd44a374